# Change UI-layout based on selected ComboBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a ComboBox like this:

```
<ComboBox>
        <ComboBoxItem>ComboBox Item #1</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>ComboBox Item #2</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>ComboBox Item #3</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

and I below that I have a grid, where the rest of the UI is. And I wanted to ask what the best way would be to display a other ui for each of the items.

Like for "Item #1" I'd like to have a radio button and a text field and for "Item #2" id like to display some data in a TextBlock, ... (Note: the ComboBox should stay at the same position to switch)

I'm not quiet sure how to implement this right with the MVVM-Model and I didn't find something useful for my problem in the internet so far.

Comment: Bind the `ComboBox.ItemsSource` to an `IEnumerable<ViewModel>` like you would with a TabControl, then put a `ContentPresenter Content="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ComboBox}` and use DataTemplates, like you would with a TabControl. Use `DisplayMemberPath` to define what text appears in each comboboxitem

Comment: ahh do you mean something like this [link](http://iswwwup.com/t/1e1e7df02a4d/c-how-to-design-a-tabpage-when-the-tabcontrols-itemssource-is-bind-to-a-.html)? thx for the fast reply. Oh didnt read your edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work due to the help of HighCores comment.
I looked at this [link](http://iswwwup.com/t/1e1e7df02a4d/c-how-to-design-a-tabpage-when-the-tabcontrols-itemssource-is-bind-to-a-.html) about TabControl and transfered it to ComboBox.

So my XAML looks like this:

```
    <ComboBox Name="RouteOptions"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}"
              DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"/>

    <ContentPresenter 
              Content="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=RouteOptions}"/>
```

And for the rest I just followed the instructions of the answer of the mentioned link.